# Transfer Windows 10 Home licence to new PC

Tags: windows-10

I am changing PC and would like to use Windows 10 on the new one.  It's OK if the old one stops working.

On the old PC, I had Windows 7 Home and used the free online upgrade.  I still have the Windows 7 original media and product key.

Is it possible to activate Windows 10 on the new PC?

Comment: If it was a retail version, yes, but I don't know what the procedure is; if OEM, no.

Comment: Will it work if I deactivate my Win10, then install the Win7 on the new PC and do online upgrade?

Comment: I would have thought so, but I've never done it. Saira's answer seems to cover most of the issues.

Comment: why is the -1?  It seems like this would be a fairly common question and searching this site didn't find any duplicate  (perhaps because whenever it is asked it gets -1 so is not found by future searches...)

Comment: I have no idea: I believe in positive responses, and whenever I mark a question down I always say why, together with advice on how to improve it. Unfortunately anonymous mark-downs are a feature of the site: I proposed a change, but it was rejected, so we have to live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was a OEM license then NO because OEM licenses are tied to the very first computer you install and activate it. But if the RETAIL version of Windows 7 installed on your old PC then you use the Windows 10 to your new PC provided license in no longer be in active use on your old PC. You have two options to deactivate the Windows 10 license on your old PC:

1. Format or reset your old PC: Format your computer or reset your computer using the “Reset” option in Windows 10.
2. Uninstall Windows 10 key: Press Windows Key + X and choose Command Prompt (Admin). Type the following command which uninstall the Windows 10 key from your PC: `slmgr.vbs /upk`

**Additional info (If you’re directly installing Windows 10 on your new PC)**: When prompted during the installation of Windows for a product key, click I don’t have a product key and then you will get the option to select the edition you’re licensed for i.e Windows 7 Home Edition.

Comment: OK . I selected "I dont have a product key" when installing Win 10, but it did not give me any further prompts.  After everything was up and running, I went into Activation and entered my Win 7 Home key, and it seemed to accept it without saying anything.

Comment: @M.M, When I transferred my Windows 7 Professional retail license to my new PC I got this option to enter the Windows 7 key after I clicked "I Don't have a product key." What you did is also going to work because this How-To-Geek guide http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/ says:

"If you’ve never installed and activated Windows 10 on this computer before, you’ll see the activation screen. Enter your Windows 10 key here. If you don’t have one, but you have a valid 7, 8, or 8.1 key, enter it here instead."

Comment: OK. Is it possible that the MS servers will notice there are now 2 PCs using the same key and deactivate one of them?  Should I manually deactivate the old one?

Comment: @M.M, yes, you should deactivate the old one. MS servers will definitely catch the same key running on the two different systems as soon as you connect to the Internet. Btw, If you found my answer useful, you can accept it as an answer to your question.